# I am looking for fxml update on startup

Tags: javafx

In javafx there are onclickaction , ondragaction, etc 
But I cant find  something like onstartupaction that perform an action when the application starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Application javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html) for an instance of the application lifecycle.  When your application starts, it's [start method](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html#start%28javafx.stage.Stage%29) will be called.

Initialization of fxml is different from application startup, as one application may have many fxml documents loaded many times, each time having a new controller instantiatd and it's initialization method called.  This is described in the [@FXML Controllers section of the Introduction to FXML documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#fxml_annotation).

In the following controller, the initialize method will be invoked by the FXMLLoader. Every time it loads an FXML document referencing the controller class, the loader will create a new controller instance and invoke initialize on it.

```
public class MyController implements Initializable {
  @FXML private Button button;

  @FXML
  protected void initialize()
    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I know that I can call action from MyController when a button is clicked , But what I ascked for is how to call an action when the whole fxml is loaded .
so I guess I cant do that in fxml ??

Comment: ok thank you!!understood now;!! I am new to javafx, pardon me!!
have a nice day!!