# How to auto start an action event on a 2nd controller when loading its FXML file in JavaFX with FXML?

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I have 2 FXML files, with 2 controllers. Each FXML file has its own controller. First scene has a button that takes you to the 2nd scene.  Now my question is, how can I start executing  the commands "label.setText ("Hello There \n");" in my 2nd controller without doing any additional ActionEvent other than the button click from scene1 to take me to scene2 .

MainController:

```
public void startNewScene() throws IOException {
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXML.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

2nd controller as per the example in the comment below from " ItachiUchiha"

```
public class MyController implements Initializable {
    @FXML private Button button;
    @FXML private Label label;

    @FXML
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
               label.setText("hello there,  you clicked me"); 
            }
    }
);
    }
}
```

Now the 2nd scene gets uploaded but nothing is outputted to the screen or to the console. But when I click on the button on scene everything works.

So I tried to set "onMouseClicked"  and "onAction" to initialize and/or handle  for both label and button but I get errors "handler method not found." in the FXML file

FXML file:

```
<GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="ciacv.MyController">
  <columnConstraints>
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
  </columnConstraints>
  <rowConstraints>
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
  </rowConstraints>
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="label"  />
      <Button fx:id="button" mnemonicParsing="false"  text="Button" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

Comment: Try placing `label.setText ("Hello There \n");` inside the `intialize()` of your second controller. Whenever your second fxml is loaded, the initialize() method of your controller is called. For more information read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751408/i-am-looking-for-fxml-update-on-startup/17752416#17752416)

Comment: I tried it but it's giving me errors. I also tried the linked explanation  and it's giving me errors as well. Do you have a working example that I can use. I have been looking at this for some time now and no luck thus far. Thanks!!

Comment: Please update your question with what you have tried and what errors do you receive.

Comment: updated, thx again for looking into it!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fx:id` of your button in your fxml is `butn1` where as in your controller you have are trying to inject the Button with declaration

```
@FXML private Button button;
```

You need to use the same `fx:id` that you have declared in the fxml to correctly inject the object into its reference i.e.

```
@FXML private Button butn1;
```

---

**Edit** - As per the comments

You need to set the `Scene on the Stage`

```
public void startNewScene() throws IOException {
    root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXML.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

---

**Edit - 2**

No you have not written anything to set the text in the label when the fxml gets loaded.

You have just written

```
label.setText("hello there,  you clicked me");`
```

inside the button's action. If you need to set the text in label at load, you can write the following statement inside `intialize()`

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    // Set Label's text intialize() is called
    label.setText("Helll There...");`
    // Set Label's text on Button's action
    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
           label.setText("hello there,  you clicked me"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: updated the question, scene starts fine but nothing gets outputted to the screen. Thanks again for looking into this.

Comment: Updated the question. That's how I have it in my first controller. Right now, I have the scene attached in my first controller, the 2nd scene load just fine, but nothing is getting outputted. but when I fire the button I get the output. The action is not getting triggered automaticly somehow......

Comment: I do not understand your question. `..but when I fire the button I get the output.` are you talking about the button in the second stage? If yes, you already have the button getting displayed.

Comment: in my FXML there is a one button and a label with no visible text, now when I go from scene 1 to 2, in my 2nd controller I set label.setText("Hello There...."). this action doesn't get triggered automatically and I have to click on the button on my FXML to display that text.

Comment: Updated my answer again

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean by `abstract`. But you can definitely go through [Introduction to FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html) and [JavaFX: Mastering FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/)